# Spring not able to find classpath resource with @PropertySource

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, classpath

I am using `@PropertySource` in my datasource configuration file to get property files located on classpath. Below is my project structure.

[image]

I believe I can do it in two ways:

1. By creating a package in `src` folder and add them there. As `src` folder is already included in the classpath in eclipse, following should work.

> @PropertySources({
>           @PropertySource("classpath: com/spring/property/general.properties"),
>           @PropertySource("classpath: com/spring/property/hibernate.properties")
>   })

2. Second way is to create a `resources` folder and add it to the classpath and following should work

> @PropertySources({
>           @PropertySource("classpath: general.properties"),
>           @PropertySource("classpath: hibernate.properties")
>   })

In my case neither of the two is working. Being an intermediate java developer this still confuses me. Can anybody guide me in the right direction. And also how we can configure classpath resources for Spring in a production environment.

**EDIT**:
I have changed my project structure to include properties file in `src/java/resources` and I can see the `resources` folder in build path. Still `.properties` are not found by spring.

[image]

Comment: You are using maven... Non java resources must be in `src/main/resources` not `src/main/java` as they will be ignored.

Comment: Agree with M. Deinum. You can use Resource class to get the resource file


import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

Resource applicationProperties = new ClassPathResource("application.properties");

Comment: @M.Deinum I have changed the project structure. But it is still not working.

Comment: What isn't working? Make sure that eclipse and maven actually work together. Also when using maven there is no such thing as `src/main/test`... I strongly suggest reading on how a maven project structure should look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anybody facing problem with usign `.properties` files in Spring 4+, look at the thread below to match your setup with that of OP. Setup is all good except for a whitespace in configuration.

[Not able to inject .properties file into Spring MVC 4.3 using @PropertySource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40355105/not-able-to-inject-properties-file-into-spring-mvc-4-3-using-propertysource)

Comment: it is the same with a non-maven project?