# Not able to inject .properties file into Spring MVC 4.3 using @PropertySource

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties

I want to use `.properties` file to read mysql and hibernate properties using `Environment` and `@PropertySources` but I am getting error below

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [ /com/properties/persistence/mysqldb.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Here is my project strutucture

[image]

PersistenceConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.hp.model.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySources({
@PropertySource("classpath: /com/properties/persistence/mysqldb.properties"),
@PropertySource("classpath: /com/properties/persistence/hibernate.properties")})
public class PersistenceConfig {

@Autowired
Environment env;
.......
```

I have checked my build path and `src/main/resources` is on the classpath as shown below

[image]

Any clue what I am missing ?

Comment: Remove the whitespace. `classpath:com/properties/persistence/mysqldb.properties`.

Comment: @M.Deinum whitespace was causing the problem. Nothing wrong with the setup. thnx

Answer (score 5):

As @Deinum pointed out you will need to remove the whitespace from `classpath:com/properties/persistence/mysqldb.properties`